# Configure Django1.6 with python 27 on openshift Step by step

Tags: django, python-2.7, hosting, web-hosting, openshift

Openshift had made some changes to their files in python 2.7 application.

So I would like to know how to host a `django16` site on `python27` in OPENSHIFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Steps to create in OPENSHIFT

### 1. Create a Project:

- create a python2.7 application in [openshift](http://www.openshift.com)
- create an sshkey `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and upload the publickey `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

### 2. Clone the Project:

- clone the app.(ie `git clone ssh://52fb16fa4382..@n-suhail.rhcloud.com/~/git/n.git/`)

**Now a folder is created with files** : `requirements.txt`,`setup.py` and `wsgi.py`

### 3. Copy the project folder to that directory.

So that the project tree is something like:

```
requirements.txt
setup.py
wsgi.py
mysite/
    manage.py
    sample/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

### 4. Edit the file `wsgi.py`

**Replace the whole content by:**

**note:** You need to correct the path of `settings.py`(`sample.settings`) and the path of your project(`mysite`)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'sample.settings'
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'],'mysite'))

virtenv = os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'],'virtenv')
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:pass

from django.core.handlers import wsgi
application = wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

### 5. Add your project's requirements in `requirements.txt` file :

something like:

```
Django
```

### 6. Commit and push to server

- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "Initialization"`
- `git push`